# How to flatten the json produced by Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I'm starting out with Rabl and are trying to include a parent attribute but at the same level as the child.

This is what I have so far..

```
class Usertag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tag
    attr_accessible :user_id, :tag_id
end
```

My index.json.rabl

```
object @usertag
attributes :id
child :tag do
  attributes :name
end
```

Produces

```
[{"usertag":{"id":1,"tag":{"name":"Dolor et non."}}},
```

How do I flatten the child node in the template so it produces

```
[{"usertag":{"id":1,"name":"Dolor et non."
```

Thanks!

Comment: Found it - use the @glue tag in Rabl.

Comment: You know you can answer your own question, right?

Comment: @Cupcake Is there some way to circumvent the 48 hour delay in answering your questions? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: That's a 48 hour delay to ***accepting*** the answer to your own question, not for writing an answer. You can write your own answer immediately.

Comment: I generally wait till the 48 hours is up and put the answer with the mark on it - is that alright with you? Is this some egregious misstep you feel the need to point out?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, I'm just saying, you can answer your own question at ***any time***, including immediately, and even simultaneously as you post the answer. The only restriction that exists is that you can't accept the answer that you've written until 48 hours later, the Stack Exchange application itself won't allow you to.

Comment: Oops, slight correction. The 48 hours restriction begins [from the time the question is posted](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), not from the time that you post an answer to the question.